# Added Java EE after installing new software but Dynamic Web project is not available yet

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, tomcat9

I am continue trying to solve the error
I added Java EE on my eclipse after that I Can't see the option **'Dynamic Web Project'**.And I can't also see the option **Server**.
[here i am just watching red box mark on server tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrEyM.png)

[Red Box icon is showing here before Java EE. I am not understanding what the mess it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7di93.png)

I tried all the methods for this subject but didn't get the output.

Comment: How did you add "Java EE" to your Eclipse, because it looks as though you have not?

Comment: I went to 'Install New Software' and I typed the url ''http://download.eclipse.org/releases''. Then I select the option Java EE , XML etc. and Now I can switch to Java EE

Comment: Actually i was able to see the option "Dynamic Web Project" in beginning after installation but now i am not able to see it and I can't also see the Servers.

Comment: Were you starting with the year old 2019-03 release? What version of Java is being used to run Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Discard whatever type/version of Eclipse you have installed and download the following one:

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2020-06/R/eclipse-jee-2020-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip

Note that [Eclipse comes for various programming/modelling langauges](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) and it looks like either you have selected a wrong type or an outdated version.